# How do I measure the ACTUAL or RAW speed of a server

Tags: webserver

I need advice on whether I should move my Wordpress site from a sharing hosting environment to a Linux VPS server.
My goal: to speed up the site. Even though I've reduced the number of plugins on my wordpress, my initial server response time is over 1.5 seconds. I read VPS would give me better performance.
I bought the 4GB KVM VPS here: https://www.racknerd.com/BlackFriday/
But before I spend the resources on installing lamp and other things necessary to move my site: how do I compare the RAW speed of my current shared hosting and this server I just purchased?
I hope I make sense. I mean all things equal, how can I tell if this server is actually faster than my current shared hosting environment?
I apologize for my untechnical newbie terminology. This is why I need help.

Comment: What use is any "raw" speed, however that might be defined? You want to run an application (Wordpress), so nothing else matters. // If you want to know what's slow, "profiling" is what you want to do.

Comment: Hi @DanielB, thanks for your tip. I'm reading up on profiling now. I appreciate it. Regarding "raw" speed, my point is there a way to measure if the VPS server would be a "faster" environment for the website. Could I, for example, measure the server's response times? Essentially, I am asking how one can compare two servers with each other and what metrics should one consider when the purpose is web hosting.

Comment: "raw server response time" really won't help you much,. For wordpress, installing a good caching plugin usually resolves the issue. A VPS really only should be needed for very large sites (thousands of posts) or heavily visited sites. First,  read something like this: https://wpengine.com/resources/reduce-server-response-time/#5_Ways_to_Reduce_Initial_Server_Response_Time

Answer (score 2):

The main metric categories are **Disk**/storage, **Network**, and **CPU**/processing speed. One of those will be the bottleneck in any operation. There are plenty of sub-categories, like disk read vs write speed, but they're not always relevant to your application

Depending on what the webservice is doing, you might hit all three in a given request (e.g. database lookup > file read > file transfer), which is why profiling is important for understanding why something is fast or slow. Wordpress for example doesn't cache much by default, so it tends to wait on disk speed more than you might expect